# Ring buffered SSBO with compute shader

Tags: opengl, graphics, compute-shader

I am performing view frustum culling and generating draw commands on the GPU in a compute shader and I want to pass the bounding volumes in a SSBO. Currently I am using just a large uniform array but I want to go bigger thus the need to move to a SSBO.

The thing I want to accomplish is something a kin to the AZDO approach of using triple buffering in order to avoid sync issues when updating the SSBO by only updating one third of the buffer while guarding the rest with fences.

Is this possible to combine with the compute shader dispatch or should I just create three different SSBOs and then bind each of them accordingly?

The solution as I currently see it would be to somehow tell the following drawcall to only fetch data in the SSBO from a certain offset (0 * buffer_size, 1 * buffer_size, etc). Is this even possible?

**Render loop**

```
  /* Fence creation omitted for clarity */

  // Cycle round updating different parts of the buffer
  const uint32_t buffer_idx = (frame % gl_state.bvb_num_partitions);
  uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)gl_state.bvbp + buffer_idx * gl_state.bvb_buffer_size;
  std::memcpy(ptr, bounding_volumes.data(), gl_state.bvb_buffer_size);
  const uint32_t gl_bv_binding_point = 3; // Shader hard coded
  const uint32_t offset = buffer_idx * gl_state.bvb_buffer_size;
  glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, gl_bv_binding_point, gl_state.bvb, offset, gl_state.bvb_buffer_size);

  // OLD WAY: glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_state.cull_shader.gl_program, "spheres"), NUM_OBJECTS, &bounding_volumes[0].pos.x);

  glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_state.cull_shader.gl_program, "frustum_planes"), 6, glm::value_ptr(frustum[0]));

  glDispatchCompute(NUM_OBJECTS, 1, 1);

  glMemoryBarrier(GL_COMMAND_BARRIER_BIT | GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT); // Buffer objects affected by this bit are derived from the GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER binding.
```

**Bounding volume SSBO creation**

```
// Bounding volume buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &gl_state.bvb);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, gl_state.bvb);
gl_state.bvb_buffer_size = NUM_OBJECTS * sizeof(BoundingVolume);
gl_state.bvb_num_partitions = 3; // 1 for application, 1 for OpenGL driver, 1 for GPU
GLbitfield flags = GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT;
glBufferStorage(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, gl_state.bvb_num_partitions * gl_state.bvb_buffer_size, nullptr, flags);
gl_state.bvbp = glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, gl_state.bvb_buffer_size * gl_state.bvb_num_partitions, flags);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you not simply bind that particular range of the buffer for use here? Indeed, I don't see any code here for binding the SSBO.

Comment: Yes! That was the part I was missing, I added it in. Thanks!! Now I wonder if there is any way to avoid having to call glBindBufferRange each and every time? Is there any other way to structure the program that is more efficient perhaps?